# Prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)^{4}\geq\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{x_{i+4}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, fractions, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How to prove this inequality? 
$$\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{x_2}{x_3}\right)^{4}+\dotsb+\left(\frac{x_n}{x_1}\right)^{4}\geq \frac{x_1}{x_5}+\frac{x_2}{x_6}+\dotsb+\frac{x_{n-3}}{x_1}+\frac{x_{n-2}}{x_2}+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_3}+\frac{x_n}{x_4},$$ where $x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n>0.$

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: sounds somewhat like an AMGM generalization to me... try doing some induction too

Comment: how does it look if $$n=2,3$$?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, only for n=5, 6, ...

Comment: how it looks then?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, $$\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{x_2}{x_3}\right)^{4}+\dotsb+\left(\frac{x_5}{x_1}\right)^{4}\geq \frac{x_1}{x_5}+\frac{x_5}{x_4}+\frac{x_4}{x_3}+\frac{x_3}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_1},$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\frac{x_1}{x_2}=y_1$, $\frac{x_2}{x_3}=y_2$, $\frac{x_3}{x_4}=y_3$, $\frac{x_4}{x_5}=y_4$,...

Hence, $\prod\limits_{i=1}^ny_i=\frac{x_1}{x_{n+1}}$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^4\geq\sum_{i=1}^ny_iy_{i+1}y_{i+2}y_{i+3},$$
which is just AM-GM:
 $$\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^4=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i^4+y_{i+1}^4+y_{i+2}^4+y_{i+3}^4)\geq\sum_{i=1}^ny_iy_{i+1}y_{i+2}y_{i+3}$$.
Done!

Comment: Lol. Genius. Thx!

Comment: How  $$\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^4=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i^4+y_{i+1}^4+y_{i+_2}^4+y_{i+3}^4)$$?

Comment: @Doublench Because $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_i^4=\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_{i+1}^4=\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_{i+2}^4=\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_{i+3}^4$

Comment: nope man. How ? For example, n=5.

Comment: @Doublench For $n=5$ we have $y_1^4+y_2^4+y_3^4+y_4^4+y_5^4=\frac{1}{4}((y_1^4+y_2^4+y_3^4+y_4^4)+(y_2^4+y_3^4+y_4^4+y_5^4)+(y_3^4+y_4^4+y_5^4+y_1^4)+(y_4^4+y_5^4+y_1^4+y_2^4)+(y_5^4+y_1^4+y_2^4+y_3^4))$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^5 y_{i+2}^4 = y_{3}^{4}+y_{4}^{4}+y_{5}^{4}+y_{6}^{4}+y_{7}^{4}+y_{8}^{4}$ <br>
$y_{6}^{4}, y_{7}^{4}, y_{8}^{4} - ???$

Comment: @Doublench No! $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_{i+2}^4=y_3^4+y_4^4+...+y_n^4+y_1^4+y_2^4$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^5y_{i+2}^4=y_3^4+y_4^4+y_5^4+y_1^4+y_2^4$

Comment: thx! I understood all proof.